# Mailto <a> tag not firing Mail app on some Iphones' Safari

Tags: html, iphone, safari

My client told me that them and their website's visitors with iPhones can't open the mailto link inside an  tag.

```
<a href="mailto:test@email.com" title="E-mail"><span itemprop="email">test@email.com</span></a>
```

The link should open your email app or whatever behaviour is associated with mailto.
Since I don't an iPhone I tried Browswerstack.
On this site https://www.rublanch.com/en mail in the footer:

1. On iOS 16.7.5 (real device, of the client) the click triggers nothing.
2. On iOS from 17 to 14 and 11 on Browerstack the link opens Mail.
3. On iOS 12-13 on Browerstack it behaves like 1).
4. On iOS 17.3 real device the link opens Mail.

Things get even weirder because the device 1) *can* open "send us an email" here https://www.altabadia.org/en/tourist-office-badia.html which is basically using the same  tag, mine just has the title attribute. The same link is not working on devices 3) on Browserstack.

What could be the culprit of this behavior?

EDIT: I just wrote a telephone here by mistake. On the example website there's always been an email adress!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have a telephone number in your example code?

Comment: SORRY! It was a just a mistake I did here. I corrected it. On the example website there's a mail adress!

Comment: That was unfortunate, because now people didn't focus on the real problem you say you have... let's see if that happens now. I can't help you because I don't have an iPhone at hand.

Comment: I just tried the link on my iPhone and it opened the mail app, I use   iOS 16.3

Comment: That's so weird.

Comment: As I said, I don't have an iPhone at hand, but something in the OS must know which App to open for an email link. I assume this is called the "default email app" in iOS. And yes, there is a way to set it, see: [Change the default web browser or email app on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/104975). Maybe this isn't configured correctly on the iPhone that doesn't work?

Comment: The issue is that the same iPhone does open the Mail app on the other site I linked (altabadia.org) that would drop the "default app" theory...

Comment: OK, good point. In your example page the email link has a `target="_blank"`. That makes no sense, and shouldn't be there. The page at https://www.rublanch.com/en has a lot of code, which I can't all check, but it can be done automatically. Have a look at [this HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). The page has 792 problems, like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your href attribute should contain "mailto:test@email.com". If you need for a number, it should be `href="tel:+44123456789"`. You can look into [mailto](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/mailto-link-how-to-make-an-html-email-link-example-code/) for more understanding.

```
<a href="mailto:test@email.com" title="E-mail"><span itemprop="email">test@email.com</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your href attribute its wrong, should contain an email, like test@email.com

```
<a href="mailto:test@email.com" title="E-mail"><span itemprop="email">test@email.com</span></a>
```